# ECG QRS detection using python

Tags: python

#### Problem:

ECG QRS detection using python

#### Code:

```
self.signal_frequency = 250  # Set ECG device frequency in samples per second here.
self.filter_lowcut = 0.0
self.filter_highcut = 15.0
self.filter_order = 1

def bandpass_filter(self, data, lowcut, highcut, signal_freq, filter_order=5):
    """
    Method responsible for creating and applying Butterworth filter.
    :param deque data: raw data
    :param float lowcut: filter lowcut frequency value
    :param float highcut: filter highcut frequency value
    :param int signal_freq: signal frequency in samples per second (Hz)
    :param int filter_order: filter order
    :return array: filtered data
    """
    nyquist_freq = 0.5 * signal_freq
    low = lowcut / nyquist_freq
    high = highcut / nyquist_freq
    #N, Wn = signal.buttord([20, 50], [14, 60], 3, 40, True)
    #b, a = signal.butter(N, Wn, 'band', True)
    b, a = signal.butter(filter_order, [low, high], btype="band",analog=False)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y
```

I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 < Wn < 1
```